Why does my new untitled file sometimes switch to a '!' icon in the tab handle while I type in VS code?
I've created a file in VS code. It's  just a plain text file:

If I change the name it goes away. My question is what is the '!' Icon? And why is the text  Blue?
I found a couple posts that suggest it's a merge issue. But this is a  newly created folder and newly created file, and other than suggesting it's a merge issue I haven't found a post that suggests a way to resolve the issue The folder is not part of a git repository.

This is due to automatic language detection. The ! icon is the icon in your current icon theme for YAML files. You can see in the right side of the status bar, it's showing that your file is in the YAML language mode due to autodetection. The ML model trying to autodetect the language is sometimes detecting the contents of your new untitled file as YAML as you are typing. If you want to modify the behaviour, I've written about autodetection configuration here.
